# Splitting a list into an array and then looping through that array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of securities that are pipe delimited that I'm splitting into an array which works well. The issue I'm facing is that the ubound of my array is showing as zero, even though I can expand the array in my watch window and see the list of securities. Hoping someone could assist - code below:

```
tmpList = Right(tmpList, Len(tmpList) - 1)
arr_SecList = Array(Split(tmpList, Delim))

 Debug.Print (tmplist)

For i = LBound(arr_SecList) To UBound(arr_SecList)
    Debug.Print (arr_SecList(i))
Next
```

The result of the debug line is Test1|Test2|Test3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can use `Split` directly to get an array without using `Array`

```
tmpList = Right(tmpList, Len(tmpList) - 1)
Debug.Print (tmpList)
arr_SecList = Split(tmpList, Delim)

 Debug.Print (UBound(arr_SecList))

For i = LBound(arr_SecList) To UBound(arr_SecList)
    Debug.Print (arr_SecList(i))
Next
```

Comment: Okay so that worked perfectly. Mind walking me through why it did work? And this is my first ever question, do I need to do anything to mark this as the right answer? I tried upvoting but I guess since my account doesn't have enough activity it doesn't impact the public score.

Comment: `Split(tmpList, Delim)` alone creates a zero-based 1-dim array out of the (variant) tmpList. Embedding this array in another array (*jagged array* or *array of arrays*) would be possible, but isn't needed. `Debug.Print UBound(arr_SecList)` shows the upper items boundary in this array (=items count minus 1, as indexing in a zero-based array starts at `0`, i.e. its first item) - *btw you don't need the surrounding brackets here, there is no evaluation made.* `Debug.Print arr_SecList(i)` shows the items via index (1st item = 0, 2nd = 1, ...). |`arr_SecList(0)(i)` would show the jagged alternative